# How to protect an email address in a php file?

Tags: email, php, spam, permissions

I have a continuously upgraded and minimalistically developed LAMP environment with an all-core CMS website.

The main reason that my contact form in my website is backend (PHP) instead frontend (vanilla JavaScript) is to protect my email address from spambots that might scan for email address in HTML output sources and then abuse the email address.

So, say I have created a small simple backend contact form program from 4 files (`structure.html`, `backend.php`, `frontend.js`, `style.css`) and hardcoded my current email address inside `backend.php`; this is still a file which annoying bots can find somehow (bruteforce-searching?) and accesses via some user agent (say a web browser) and read and "mine" my email address from there and still abuse it, right? If so than:

**How to protect an email address in a php file?**

Comment: The PHP source code (between the <?php and ?> tags) should not be readable to bots or any other agents that request make a request to the URL of the PHP file.  So, it shouldn't be a problem if you have an email address hard-coded in the PHP source.  If the source is readable, then you have a misconfiguration, and this is a security concern.

Comment: @mti2935 thanks ; gladly I never had a case of a PHP source being able to be read via a browser; I actually didn't finish creating such a program and I just wanted to make sure how to avoid such a situation; I should double ensure that if I navigate to the file from a browser no PHP code would appear. Thanks again !

Comment: This question is a pure programming question and is out of scope of Security SE site. I suggest to move it to SO.